# I'm trying to use ffmpeg with qt but I get undefined references errors

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, undefined-reference

I tried to solve this problem myself but I couldn't. I installed FFmpeg with msys 3 step method:

```
configure 
make 
make install
```

and tried to link every library in the .pro. At first, I got errors like an undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all()`; but after linking all the libraries they stopped and instead of them I got 6 others:

> c:\ffmpeg-3.3.3\libavutil\error.c:120: error: undefined reference to `strerror_r'
>
> c:\mingw\include\time.h:422: error: undefined reference to `__mingw_sleep'
>
> c:\mingw\include\stdlib.h:810: error: undefined reference to `__mingw_mkstemp'
>
> c:\mingw\include\stdlib.h:810: error: undefined reference to `__mingw_mkstemp'
>
> localcharset.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp__GetACP@0'
>
> collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

this is main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

extern "C" {
    #include <libavutil/frame.h>
    #include <libavutil/mem.h>
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Enter input file name." << endl;
    string inName, outName;
    cin>>inName;
    cout<<"Enter output file name."<<endl;
    cin>>outName;
    avcodec_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

and my .pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp


LIBS += -LC:\ffmpeg-3.3.3\ffmpeg\lib
LIBS += -lpthread
LIBS += -lavdevice
LIBS += -lavfilter
LIBS += -lavformat
LIBS += -lavcodec
LIBS += -lz
LIBS += -lswresample
LIBS += -lswscale
LIBS += -lavutil
LIBS += -lm
INCLUDEPATH += C:/ffmpeg-3.3.3/ffmpeg/include
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `using namespace std;` inside of `main`?

Comment: Yes i tried it and it gives the same errors doesnt matter where is using namespace std, i even tried deleting it but no change

Comment: That is likely about FFMpeg library expecting MingW C (it was built that way?) runtime from being linked with executable but the executable does not have that (different compiler adds different runtime).

Comment: It is strange that you are getting error from `\libavutil\error.c`